# Delete Bitcoin Qt Mac: System folder inflated in size, although "Application Support/Bitcoin/" and app deleted

Tags: mac, bitcoin-qt-setup

I downloaded Bitcoin Qt and the entire blockchain, now I'd like to delete it.

I followed instructions from various search results, which all instructed to delete the app and to delete all data (where the "data", the blockchain, is supposed to take up so much space) in `~/Library/Preferences/`, `~/Library/Application Support/` and `~/Library/Caches/`. This was the most comprehensive guide: https://uninstallmacapp.com/bitcoin-0-9-removal.html.

In `~/Library/Preferences/` & `~/Library/Caches/`, I couldn't find any related data. In `~/Library/Application Support/`, there was a "Bitcoin" folder (which was like 7gb in size according to right click->"Get Info"), which I moved to Trash (was emptied subsequently).

I'm sure that I chose only default options in the installation of Bitcoin Qt - no non-default directories were chosen.

Before Bitcoin Qt, under "Storage management", "System" took up like 30-50 gb. Now, it takes up 155 gb. The way I understand it, "Library" is basically my system directory. The "Library" directory, via "get info", shows a total size of 60 gb. However, in "Storage management" System is shown to occupy 155gb. I'm not sure how this makes sense. I have enabled to see all hidden files, so I'm also sure that I'm not overlooking something too obvious.

Rebooting my mac also doesn't help.

Do you have any clue where the blockchain from Bitcoin Qt could sit, so I can delete it and free up the space?

I use a MacBook Pro Early 2015, macOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6

Answer (score 1):

If you had enabled pruning, then a 7 GB Bitcoin folder makes sense.

Otherwise, you probably chose a different data directory in which case you will need to remember where it is. Try searching your computer for a file named `debug.log` or `blk00001.dat`.